# Increment field value provided another field matches a string

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to increment a value in a csv file, provided it matches a search string. Here is the script that was utilized:

```bash
awk -i inplace -F',' '$1 == "FL" { print $1, $2+1} ' data.txt
```

Contents of data.txt:

```
NY,1
FL,5
CA,1
```

Current Output:

```
FL 6
```

Intended Output:

```
NY,1
FL,6
CA,1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Never add `-i inplace` until your script is producing the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Intended Output:**
>
> NY,1 FL,6 CA,1

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
NY,1
FL,5
CA,1
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";ORS=" "}{print $1,$2+($1=="FL")}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
NY,1 FL,6 CA,1
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) is `,` and output row separator (`ORS`) is space with accordance to your requirements. Then for each line I `print` 1st field followed by 2nd field increased by *is 1st field FL?* with 1 denoting it does hold, 0 denotes it does not hold. If you want to know more about `FS` or `OFS` or `ORS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Comment: Thanks, how do I print each row with new line. Proposed solution prints everything in one line.

Comment: @VCPMuthukrishna do not set `ORS` that is replace `{FS=OFS=",";ORS=" "}` using `{FS=OFS=","}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1=="FL"{++$2} 1' data.txt
NY,1
FL,6
CA,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -F',' -lane 'if ( $F[0] eq "FL" ) { $F[1]++; } print join ",", @F;' data.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F','` : Split into `@F` on comma, rather than on whitespace.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)